# unable to catch exception?

Tags: jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

why not able to catch EmptyResultDataAccessException?

method:

```
public List<User> findUserById(Object id) {
    MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource("userid", String.valueOf(id);

    try {
             List<User> userList = myDatasource.query("select * from User where userid=:userid", paramSource, new UserMapper());
             Logger.info("number or records: " + userList.size();
    catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
    }

  return userList;
}
```

userList.size(); returns 0 but im still not able to catch the EmptyResultDataAccessException. what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't throw that exception. EmptyResultDataAccessException is thrown by things like [JdbcTemplate#queryForObject](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) that have to return a single row (so the exception is for the case where no rows are found, or where more than one row is found); the exception is listed for queryForObject in the Javadoc. Since the query method (guessing this is [JdbcTemplate#query](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query(java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper))) returns a list there's no problem returning an empty list, and no reason to throw an exception.

Comment: That kinda sucks, is there any good exception handling way to catch if a record is not found?

Comment: @Zeus: you can check the resultset size and throw an exception yourself. or use queryForObject if you want only one row.